# How to add DataFormatString in a TemplateField in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I am working with a Gridview in aspx page.
To be more specific, in a gridview, I'm working on a specific column called Price

The Price column value examples in the gridview should look something like this:

```
 Price
 1.50 AUD
10.00 AUD
15.55 AUD
100.50 AUD
```

In order to achieve this result, this is what I have tried in the aspx file:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0} AUD" >
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox1" runat="server" DataField="Product_Price" Text='<%#Eval("Price")%>' />
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers with decimals only" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
          <asp:Button ID ="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Update_Click" CommandArgument="Button7" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

When I bring the mouse cursor on DataFormatString syntax, this is the error message being shown:

```
Validation(ASP.NET): Attribute 'DataFormatString' is not a valid attribute of element 'TemplateField'
```

Where have I made the mistake ?

It would be helpful if the appropriate solution syntax is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox1" runat="server" DataField="Product_Price" Text='<%#Eval("Price","{0:c}")%>' />
```

Comment: I have added {0:c} as you have recommended but there is still green line under DataFormatString and showing that error message: Validation(ASP.NET): Attribute 'DataFormatString' is not a valid attribute of element 'TemplateField'

Comment: Yes, remove the DataFormatString attribute as it is not valid for TemplateField. It is valid for Bound fields https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_BoundField_DataFormatString

Comment: I have removed the DataFormatString attribute and when I refer back to aspx gridview design, The column value format for Price is being shown as 'Databound' with 'Update' button besides it in the textbox. That's OK. But I also want to see 'AUD' besides the 'Databound' text. In other words, the column value format for Price in Gridview design should show as 'Databound' 'AUD' in the text box.

Comment: `Text='<%#Eval("Price")%> AUD' `

Comment: I have added Text='<%#Eval("Price")%> AUD as you have recommended. Now, in the gridview design, the textbox value under the Price column is being shown as: <%#Eval("Price")%> .. Is that normal ? ... Previously it was showing 'Databound"

Comment: Yes, I am not sure why you are so cautious about design time rendering. Try running the page and also I still recommend format price using currency format `{0:c}` instead of hardcoding `AUD`.

Comment: Now everything is fine. I just have one last question.  Text='<%#Eval("Price")%> .. The Price that is inside the double quotation, Is it representing a column from database table or datafield ?

Comment: Price is the datafield name means it can be different from the database column name. Normally, both datafield and database column names are same. So when you bind ADO.NET datatable to a GridView the datafield is column name. When you bind GridView to a List of objects, the datafield will be  property name of the object

Comment: Glad, I was able to help. You can accept the answer if your issue is solved